# Calculation on numpy array without nested for loop

Tags: arrays, for-loop, nested

im trying to do some calculations on an ndarray I got. I want to subtract the mean of each value and then divide by the standard deviation. I want to do this for each individual value. The only way I found out for me to work is going for two for loops and then saving the results into a new array. Since this is a pretty large data set this will take some time and I am sure that there must be a faster way, which I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: You should provide some sample data and what code you have already tired.

Comment: Isn't it something like "(ndarray-ndarray.mean())/ndarray.stdev()"?